# Setting a closure as a variable in Swift and trying to call from Objective C class

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I defined a variable as a closure in Swift Class.
My code works fine when variable is called from Swift class. But variable is not accessible from Objective C class. Other functions I am able to call though.

```
    @objc class IAPHelper: NSObject {
    static let shared = IAPHelper()
    var purchaseStatusBlock: ((IAPHelperAlertType) -> Void)?  
     }

    called from a swift class 
    IAPHelper.shared.purchaseStatusBlock = {[weak self] (type) in
                guard let strongSelf = self else{ return }
                if type == .purchased {
                   // show an alert
                }
            } 

    I tried to call variable purchaseStatusBlock from Objective C class  
    IAPHelper.shared.purchaseStatusBlock ,
    Compiler Error :Property 'purchaseStatusBlock' not found on object of type 'IAPHelper *'
```

Here is my Objective C code:

```
#import "VMedu-Swift.h"
@interface FreeSubscriptionController ()
{ 
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

UIButton *restoreBtn = [VMEduUtil roundBtnWithFrame:CGRectMake(hmBtn.frame.origin.x-20, hmBtn.frame.origin.y+10, 70, searchImg.size.height) title:@"Restore" cornerRadius:3 backgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor] target:IAPHelper.shared action:@selector(restorePurchase)];
    restoreBtn.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [topBarView addSubview:restoreBtn];

  IAPHelper.shared.purchaseStatusBlock  ..... shows me error
}

@end
```

Another Swift Class PurchaseSubscriptionController which uses same closure variable purchaseStatusBlock works well. Here is my code

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

      IAPHelper.shared.fetchAvailableProducts()
        IAPHelper.shared.purchaseStatusBlock = {[weak self] (type) in
            guard let strongSelf = self else{ return }
            if type == .purchased {
                let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "", message: type.message(), preferredStyle: .alert)
                let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (alert) in

                    print("product purchased")
                })
                alertView.addAction(action)
                strongSelf.present(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you post your Objective-C code?

Comment: In viewDidLoad of my Objective C controller I am calling one function of my swift class IAPHelper.shared.fetchAvailableProducts; and then i am directly trying to access IAPHelper.shared.purchaseStatusBlock .

Comment: for me this works just fine, but i need to see your code in order to help you

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I edited my post, added Objective C code.

Comment: How your `IAPHelperAlertType` is defined? If it is not compatible with Objective-C, the property using the class cannot be exposed to Objective-C world.

Comment: To help you to understand my problem exactly I have followed https://hackernoon.com/swift-how-to-add-in-app-purchases-in-your-ios-app-c1dc2fc82319 tutorial to implement in app purchase. I am adding restore button in my Objective C class and all In app purchase related code mostly added to IAPHelper class . I am able to call restore function but problem is with calling a variable which returns me status.

Comment: @OOPer Thanks for your reply. I have mention above the link of tutorial I am following. I cannot post full code here . IAPHelperAlertType  is defined like this  "var purchaseStatusBlock: ((IAPHelperAlertType) -> Void)?"

Comment: @ShwetaChauhan, it's the definition for `purchaseStatusBlock`, not `IAPHelperAlertType`.

Comment: That's enum.                                                                                            enum IAPHelperAlertType{
    case disabled
    case restored
    case purchased
    
    func message() -> String{
        switch self {
        case .disabled: return "Purchases are disabled in your device!"
        case .restored: return "You've successfully restored your purchase!"
        case .purchased: return "You've successfully bought this purchase!"
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you just need to explicitly annotate some properties and types with `@objc`:

```
@objc public enum IAPHelperAlertType: Int {
    case disabled
    case restored
    case purchased
    func message() -> String{
        switch self {
        case .disabled:
            return "Purchases are disabled in your device!"
        case .restored:
            return "You've successfully restored your purchase!"
        case .purchased:
            return "You've successfully bought this purchase!"

        }
    }
}
```

(Added `:Int` as suggested by Xcode.)

```
class IAPHelper: NSObject {
    @objc static let shared = IAPHelper()
    @objc var purchaseStatusBlock: (@convention(block) (IAPHelperAlertType) -> Void)?
}
```

(Added two `@objc` and `@convention(block)`. `@convention(block)` makes the closure type compatible with Objective-C blocks.)

With these changes above, you can write something like this in your Objective-C code:

```
    IAPHelper.shared.purchaseStatusBlock(IAPHelperAlertTypeDisabled)
```

Comment: Thank You For your reply. Nice explanation. Helped me  :)

Answer (score 4):

You are using wrong `Objective-C` Code

**add a `@objc` in your enum declaration**

```
@objc
enum IAPHelperAlertType : Int{
    case aaaa
    case bbbb
}
```

**Replace this**

```
IAPHelper.shared.purchaseStatusBlock  ..... shows me error
```

**with this**

```
[[IAPHelper shared] setPurchaseStatusBlock:^(NSInteger inte) {
        NSLog(@"test");
    }];
```

Comment: I tried this still shows me error  "No visible @interface for 'IAPHelper' declares the selector 'setPurchaseStatusBlock:'"

Comment: check my updated answer @ShwetaChauhan you need to add `@objc` in your enum declaration

Comment: Ohh Yeah. It worked so well. You are the life saver :) Thank You so much.